# Is there a Notification Setting associated with "potential" Duplicates

Tags: duplicate-contacts

New to CiviCRM and learning the ropes. I know how to search for duplicates and merge them but wondering if when CiviCRM finds a potential duplicate on its own is there a setting where I can be notified by email or within CiviCRM when I log in to the Dashboard where a "cache" of potential dups is waiting for me to inspect?

Answer (score 1):

Currently, there no setting that will email or notify you about duplicates in your system. The only way is searching duplicates and merging them as mentioned by you.

Answer (score 0):

What you could do is create a group or a tag "potential duplicate". You can then use the standard contact reports to create a dashboard with member of this group/contacts who have this tag?